# Resolve SoundCloud track in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, soundcloud

First off, I'm pretty new to Ruby on Rails and the SoundCloud API so sorry if this is a stupid question.

My problem is, I'm trying to use the SoundCloud resolve track feature to get track information about a post.

Right now I have a scaffold set up that runs through each post using the

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %> 
    <%= post.soundcloud %>
<% end %>
```

`.soundcloud` is just the url of the song that I want to be resolved.

I've tried

```
<%= @client.get('/resolve', :url => <%= post.soundcloud %> ) %>
```

But then realized I can't have nested erb tags.

I've also tried passing various methods in the controller but I can't seem to figure it out.

Oh, here is what my controller looks like.

```
def index
   require 'soundcloud'
   @posts = Post.all
   @client = Soundcloud.new(:client_id => 'MY_CLIENT_ID')
   @tracks = @client.get('/resolve', :url => '') <-- Don't know what to do with this
end
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didnt check the documentation, but from looking at your code your erb file should be

```
  <% @posts.each do |post| %> 
     <%= @client.get('/resolve', url: post.soundcloud ) %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: You're correct. I should of been able to to figure that out. Must have been looking at it too long. Thanks for your help!